# Moved file to trash from command line, but it's not there

Tags: macos, haskell, recycle-bin

I used "mv .ghcup/ ~/.Trash" in terminal to delete the Haskell platform. It's a pretty big file, but when I checked Trash it wasn't there. I didn't empty the Trash before checking. I also tried creating a text file and moving it to trash using the same command, and I found the text file in the trash as expected. So where did .ghcup go?

Comment: Are you sure you are visualizing hidden files in `.Trash`? I.e., with `ls -a` or something like that. Many GUIs also do not show hidden files by default, and must be asked to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to see it in the Trash if you *show hidden files*.

This is because you moved a hidden file in `.ghcup` to the trash. The `.` preceding the filename marks the file as hidden [on most Unix based systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) such as macOS and Linux. Moving it to the Trash preserves its filename and its *hidden-ness*.

**You can view hidden files:**

In the terminal with `ls -a`. Navigate to your Trash folder and run the command.

Or in Finder, by opening the Trash and using the following [shortcut](http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/01/show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-dialog-boxes-with-commandshiftperiod/) `CMD + SHIFT + .`

Comment: CMD + SHIFT + . worked for me thanks